# Why does the injectivity of the differential implies the injectivity of the derivative(Jacobian)?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I'm reading Warner. "*Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups*." In the proof of corollary (a) in page 24, which I will present below, the book proves that the differential $df$ of the function $f: U \to \mathbb R^d$, where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^d$, is injective. Then the book uses that fact to derive that the derivative $Df(m)$ of $f$ at $m$ is injective (or equivalently the Jacobian of $f$ at $m$ is non-singular). But I don't know why the injectivity of $df$ implies the injectivity of $Df(m)$.

---

I'll write here the corollary I'm referring to. But first I'll write the definitios of tangent vector and differential because the definitions might be different in other books.

> **Definition of tangent vector** $\;$ A *tangent vector $v$ at the point $m\in M$* is a linear derivation of the algebra $\tilde F_m$. That is, for all **f**, **g**$\in\tilde F_m$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R$,
>
> (a) $v($**f**$+\lambda$**g**$) = v($**f**$) + \lambda v($**g**$)$.
>   (b) $v($**f**$ \cdot $**g**$) =$ **f**$(m)v($**g**$) +$ **g**$(m)v($**f**$)$.
>
> $M_m$ denotes the set of tangent vectors to $M$ at $m$ and is called the *tangent space to $M$ at $m$*.

In the above definition, $\tilde F_m$ is the set of germs at $m$.

> **Definition of differential** $\;$ Let $\psi: M\to N$ be $C^\infty$, and let $m\in M$. The *differential of $\psi$ at $m$* is the linear map
>   $$d\psi: M_m \to N_{\psi(m)}$$
>   defined as follows. If $v\in M_m$, then $d\psi(v)$ is to be a tangent vector at $\psi(m)$, so we describe how it operates on functions. Let $g$ be a $C^\infty$ function on a neighborhood of $\psi(m)$. Define $d\psi(v)(g)$ by setting
>   $$d\psi(v)(g) = v(g\circ\psi).$$

In the above definition the author used the convention of writing $w($**f**$)$, where $w$ is a tangent vector and **f** is a germ of $f$, as $w(f)$.
Now I'll write the corollary and the proof I mentioned. The boldfaced part in the proof in what I don't understand

> **Corollary (a)** $\;$ Assume that $\psi: M\to N$ is $C^\infty$, that $m\in M$, and that $d\psi: M_m\to N_{\psi(m)}$ is an isomorphism. Then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $m$ such that $\psi:U\to \psi(U)$ is a diffeomorphism onto the open set $\psi(U)$ in $N$.
>
> *Proof* $\;$ Observe that $\operatorname{dim} M = \operatorname{dim} N$, say $d$. Choose coordinate systems (I think they are also called "charts" in other books) $(V, \varphi)$ about $m$ and $(W, \tau)$ about $\psi(m)$ with $\psi(V)\subset W$. Let $\varphi(m) = p$ and $\tau(\psi(m)) = q$. **The differential of the map $\tau\circ\psi\circ\varphi^{-1} | \varphi(V)$ is non-singular at $p$. Thus the inverse function theorem** yields a diffeomorphism $\alpha: \tilde U\to\alpha(\tilde U)$ on a neighborhood $\tilde U$ of $p$ with $\tilde U\subset\varphi(V)$.
>   Then $\tau^{-1}\circ\alpha\circ\varphi$ is the required diffeomorphism on the neighborhood $U = \varphi^{-1}(\tilde U)$ of $m$.

To use the inverse function theorem, one needs the fact that the Jacobian in non-singular, not the differential. But why does the author just proves that the differential is non-singular?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\tau \circ \psi \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is the map $\psi$ expressed in terms of local coordinates and is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}^d$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$. Therefore, if you take the differential, which is a linear map, and you express it as a matrix with the bases induced by your choice of charts, the matrix will exactly be the Jacobian.